# Can I use this sintax in php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
   if(something==something){
      for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
 ?>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th><?php echo date("m d y");?></th>
   </tr>
</table>
    <?php
   }
  }
?>
```

If I would use sintax like thiks would the code work? I couldn't find any discussion on this, and I am new to php so every advice would be helpful and appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just try and see? ;-) A couple of remarks: `date(m d y)` needs to be quoted, like `date("m d y")`. And `for (int..)` should just be `for ($i...` - could also use a `foreach` loop, look it up in the manual.

Comment: I am getting some problems with the code I'm using but I think the problem is not in the code, but in the server.. I am politely asking if someone has some experience with the sintax like this so I can get some advice.

Comment: Use the manual http://www.php.net - and enable error-reporting, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1)` at the top of your file, after `<?php`

Comment: I know.. I was just typing quick not paying attention to  that things.. It doesn't matter what the code is,I am asking about the syntax

Comment: What part of the code are you referring to when you say "syntax"? If you can exit PHP to output HTML? Then yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with me. Helped me a lot. I couldn't find that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

1) Actually you can use php within html.

Eg : - `<h1><?php echo "hello world"; ?>` .

2) You can't use html within php. But exception if you use echo with html

Eg :- `<?php echo "<h1>Hello world</h1>"; ?>`

Comment: I agree with the above explanation

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Can I break out of PHP to output HTML like in the example?

Comment: of course, you can. You can use your result anywhere within the page if you understood security features

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML inside you PHP code.

```
<?php
    if(something==something){
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
        echo '<table>
              <tr>
              <th>'.date("Y-m-d").'</th>
              </tr>
          </table>';
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do this:

```
<?php if(something==something){ 
     for($i=0;$i<sizeof(array);$i++){
         echo "<table><tr><th>";
         echo date("m d y");
         echo "</th> </tr> </table>";
      }
 } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can break out of PHP to output HTML like OP is. No need to echo everything.